# Get Panel ID from Survey ID in Qualtrics API

Tags: qualtrics

I think this may be impossible, but I'm hoping I overlooked something.

At least in some cases, I can log in to the Qualtrics web site, look up a survey, and figure out what panel was used to distribute the survey. We use panel authentication, so I can look at the survey flow in the "Branch on successful authentication" box, and see the name of the panel used, as well as the library.

The question is, can this be done programmatically through the API? If I have the Survey ID, can I find the Panel ID and the Library ID?

I've tried the getSurvey request, of course (with and without the ExportLogic flag). Its response seems to include a SurveyFlow section that includes an Authenticator block, but I don't see anything in there about a panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've used the api to identify panel/survey associations is through getDistributions.  Unfortunately, since you are using authentication instead of invites I don't think it will work.

I haven't done it, but in your case I think you can find panel/survey associations using getPanel with Recipient history.  That means you'll have to use XML and do a lot of searching through individual panelists to see what surveys they responded to.

Comment: Yeah, you can get the Survey ID(s) using getPanel, which requires both a Panel ID and a Library ID. I think I'm going to end up doing that. You can have it return JSON, which is easier to deal with than XML. I really wanted to be able to go the other direction, though.

Comment: Yes, it is painful to have to go at it backwards, but I think it is the only way to do it.  I have to do it the same way with getDistributions...use getPanel to get a list of panels first, then loop through them with getDistributions (or getPanel in your case). The Qualtrics documentation says RecipientHistory is XML only, but I just tried it and you are correct...works with json too.